# how to place custom bootloader in floppy image

Tags: linux, dd, qemu, boot-loader, floppy

So I am creating a custom bootloader:

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

It is 512 bytes. How do I place this into a floppy image and boot with qemu?

I tried:

```
dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=floppy.img of=floppy2.img bs=512 count=1
qemu-system-i386 -fda floppy2.img
```

But the `floppy2.img` gets resized to 512 bytes instead of the normal size of 1.44MB. Is this the correct way? I would rather not use any fancy tools, if it can be done with `dd`, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is that the image file is too short, you could try appending 2879*512 zero bytes to the `floppy.img`file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=2879 bs=512 >> floppy.img
```

On the other hand, if you need to store somthing else than just the boot sector on the floppy image, you will have to create a FAT file system on it. The way to do this is to use a loop device.

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 floppy.img
sudo mkfs -t fat /dev/loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0 somedir
```

where `somedir` is an empty directory where `/dev/loop0` is mounted. You can now copy the needed files to this directory.